# Javascript set caret position in a ContentEditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have a div with `contenteditable` set. This div contains an inner div like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="key">
    <div class="innerKey">276</div>
</div>
```

The odd editable div structure comes about from the need for other functionality.

How would I go about setting the caret position to the start of the content of the inner div using javascript?

Comment: Check out [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browsers other than IE < 9, you can do this pretty simply, assuming for brevity that you added an id of "innerKey" to the inner `<div>`:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("innerKey");
var innerDivText = innerDiv.firstChild;
sel.collapse(innerDivText, 0);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaj6t/5/

If you need to support IE < 9, you can use my Rangy library to provide the cross-browser DOM Range and Selection support.

Comment: Hi, Tim! I am using IE 8 and need to do exactly the same thing. How can I use your Rangy library to set caret in a contenteditable div? Many thanks!

Comment: @Crista23: Replace `window.getSelection()` with `rangy.getSelection()`.

Comment: I included Rangy in my project and with the code above (with sel=rangy.getSelection();) I am getting a js error when calling sel.collapse (from rangy-core.js with the message no document found for node). How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: @Crista23: That sounds as though you're trying to collapse the selection in an element that either hasn't been added to the document yet or has been removed from the document. Got an example page?